# $\Pi_2$ formula true for $L_{{\omega_1}^L}$ but not for $L$

Tags: set-theory

I tried the formula

[${\forall x}{ \exists} {f} $$ {x}$ is an ordinal ${\land} {f}$is an injective function ${\land}$  $dom f =x$ ${\land}$ $ran f$ ${\subseteq} {\omega}$$]{ \lor}$ $x$ is not an ordinal.

This formula works if I assume $V=L$, because then $\omega_1 ={\omega_1}^L$ and by using mostowski isomorphism, one can show that the formula holds. But without $V=L$, I don't know how to do that.

${\omega_1}^L$ denotes the first uncountable ordinal in $L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the right candidate and it now suffices to prove that
$$
L_{\omega_{1}^{L}} \models \text{every set is countable}.
$$
Let us work in $L$ and thus write $\omega_{1}$ for $\omega_{1}^{L}$, $H_{\theta}$ for $\left( H_{\theta} \right)^{L}$ and so on. Let $x \in L_{\omega_{1}}$. Then there is
some injective $f \colon x \to \omega$, $f \in L$. There are now two
ways to prove that such an $f$ exists in $L_{\omega_{1}}$:

Version 1: Note that $L_{\omega_{1}} = H_{\omega_{1}}$. Since
$H_{\omega_{1}} \prec_{1} V$ and $L \models V = L$, we obtain that
$L_{\omega_{1}} \models \text{there is an injective function } f
\colon x \to \omega$.

Version 2: Let $F$ be the transitive closure of $f$ and note that $F$
is countable. Fix some sufficiently large $\theta$ and let
$H \prec H_{\theta}$ be the Skolem hull of $\{ F , f \}$ in
$H_{\theta}$. Let $\sigma \colon T \equiv H$ be the transitive
collapse of $H$. Since $T$ is countable, the condensation lemma yields
that $T = L_{\alpha}$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$. Now, since
$F$ is transitive and $f \subseteq F$, we know that the Mostowski
collapse restricted to $f$ is the identity and thus $f =
\sigma^{-1}(f) \in T = L_{\alpha} \subseteq L_{\omega_{1}}$. (This proves the stronger fact that any such $f$ actually lies in $L_{\omega_{1}}$.)

Comment: Not that I'm complaining, your answer is far better than mine; but it's odd how the main point is that you just said "we may WLOG assuming $V=L$", and its' fine, and when I say that, it was met with additional questions...

Comment: @Asaf I agree. I should have simply said that we work in $L$. The only reason I 'assumed' $V=L$ is to simplify the notation, e.g. I didn't want to write $\left( H_{\omega_{1}^{L}} \right)^{L}$. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. You need to exclude the case where $x$ is not an ordinal. It is true that every set in $L_{\omega_1^L}$ is countable there.
2. The assumption that $V=L$ is true in $L$, which is where you are interested in showing this sentence is false.

Comment: It is true that every set in $L_{{\omega_1}^L}$ is countable. But does this means that my formula holds? My concern is that after relativization, I need to show that ${\omega_1}^{L_{{\omega_1}^L}}={\omega_1}^L$. That's where I got stuck.

Comment: I think that if I can show ${\omega_1}={{\omega_1}^L}$, then I am done.

Comment: There is no $\omega_1^{L_{\omega_1^L}}$. And you don't have to show that. Since even if $\omega_1^L<\omega_1$, there are still sets in $L$ which are uncountable.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to show my formula works.

Comment: Because after relativization, I have to find for each $x \in L_{{\omega_1}^L}$, an injective function in $L_{{\omega_1}^L}$ that witnesses countability of $x$. I can certainly find such a witness in$V$, but not sure how to find it in $L_{{\omega_1}^L}$.

Comment: Remember that $L\models\omega_1=\omega_1^L$. Now recall the definition of $L_{\omega_1^L}$.